# ManualResetEvent.WaitOne is always hanging in ASP.NET MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

I used the remote cloud server to store my images.If I use the console to execute these code ,it works well ,but in asp.net mvc it is always hanging on the "**WaitOne()**"

```
    public class UploadUtil
{

    public static string  UploadBase64(string bucket,string filelocation)
    {
        //qiniu.Config.ACCESS_KEY = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ACCESS_KEY"];
        //qiniu.Config.SECRET_KEY = System.Configuration.ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SECRET_KEY"];
        qiniu.Config.InitFromAppConfig();

        string qiniuKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string returnUrl = string.Empty;

        ManualResetEvent done = new ManualResetEvent(false);
        jpegToBase64 jpeg = new jpegToBase64(filelocation);
        QiniuFile qfile = new QiniuFile(bucket, qiniuKey);
        qfile.UploadCompleted += (sender, e) => {
            returnUrl = e.RawString;
            Console.Write(e.RawString);
            done.Set();

        };
        qfile.UploadFailed += (sender, e) => {
            QiniuWebException qe = (QiniuWebException)e.Error;
            Console.WriteLine(qe.Error.ToString());
        };
        qfile.UploadString((int)jpeg.Filesize, "image/png", jpeg.Base64Content);
        done.WaitOne();
        return returnUrl;

    }

}
```

the actionresult looks like this,if I use the normal ActionResult ,the error would occurd ,so I have to use Task

```
    public Task<ActionResult> TestUpload()
    {
        var s = UploadUtil.UploadBase64("kmsfan", @"D:\\b.jpg");
        return null;

    }
```

Comment: Blocking code has no place on a webserver and will lead to scaling issues fairly quickly. Going async and using a `TaskCompletionSource` in place of the MRE and awaiting its `Task` would be preferable here.

Comment: @spender hi,could you show me the code ?because I am not familiar with your explain.

Comment: You are Blocking the Synchronization context, thus causing deadlock, use `Async Await` for MVC calls, which will not cause the deadlock

Comment: The method in your controller is not async and should not return a task ... void return type.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your ManualResetEvent will never be signaled if the upload fails. You should avoid blocking synchronization code in a server environment.

Use a [TaskCompletionSource](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dd449174(v=vs.110).aspx) to represent your asynchronous upload task :

```
public class UploadUtil
{

    public static Task<string> UploadBase64Async(string bucket,string filelocation)
    {
       var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>();
       qiniu.Config.InitFromAppConfig();

        string qiniuKey = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        jpegToBase64 jpeg = new jpegToBase64(filelocation);
        QiniuFile qfile = new QiniuFile(bucket, qiniuKey);
        qfile.UploadCompleted += (sender, e) => {
            var returnUrl = e.RawString;
            Console.Write(returnUrl);
            tcs.SetResult(returnUrl);    
        };
        qfile.UploadFailed += (sender, e) => {
            QiniuWebException qe = (QiniuWebException)e.Error;
            Console.WriteLine(qe.Error.ToString());
            tcs.SetException(qe);  
        };
        qfile.UploadString((int)jpeg.Filesize, "image/png", jpeg.Base64Content);
        return tcs.Task;    
    }

}
```

Controller :

```
public async Task<string> TestUpload()
{
    var s = await UploadUtil.UploadBase64Async("kmsfan", @"D:\\b.jpg");
    return s;
}
```

Comment: Don't you have the Async version of `UploadCompleted` event, that would make it much simpler to implement

Comment: @Guillaume From .Net 4.5 onward wouldn't `Task.FromResult`, a better option than `TaskCompletionSource`

Comment: I don't think Task.FromResult will work here. Task.FromRresult is usefull when you already have the result (synchronously), here the task is asynchronous.

Comment: I have checked it can indeed be directly replaced using `Task.FromResult ` and `Task.FromException`, which are introduced from .Net 4.5 onward and more efficient than `TaskCompletionSource`, as its like mocking the Async API

Comment: Also  this is not correct - `var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource()`, leads to compilation issue, shall be `var tcs = new TaskCompletionSource<string>()`

Comment: @MrinalKamboj, thanks, I edited my code. I'll reply to your answer about Task.FromResult